# Divide columns, but skipping rows

Tags: r

I have the following dataset, where every other row contains a string.

```
m1 <- c(1, "2", 3, "4")
m2 <- c(2, "3", 4, "5")

dta <- data.frame(m1=m1, m2=m2)
```

I would like to divide m1 by m2, but skipping the rows where I have a string.

```
dta$ratio <- dta$m1 / dta$m2
```

Comment: All the elements have string, because it is converting to character class in a `vector`.  You can check the `str(dta)`

Comment: This is conceptually flawed since in R there are no mixed type vectors. It means, that it must be either a numeric or character vector.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in a `vector` because it allows only a single `type`.  So, if there is a single element that is `character`, it converts the whole vector to `character` class.  However, this can be done if it is a `list`

```
m1 <- list(1, "2", 3, "4")
m2 <- list(2, "3", 4, "5")
i1 <- sapply(m1, is.numeric) & sapply(m2, is.numeric)
unlist(m1[i1])/unlist(m2[i1])
```

Answer (score 1):

All values in dta are character because if c combines character and numeric the result is all character; however, given that all cells are composed of digits we could still convert to numeric and divide without skipping.

```
transform(dta, ratio = as.numeric(m1) / as.numeric(m2))
##   m1 m2     ratio
## 1  1  2 0.5000000
## 2  2  3 0.6666667
## 3  3  4 0.7500000
## 4  4  5 0.8000000
```

If there were non-digit characters then we could check for them and only divide the numeric ones:

```
# changed from question
m1 <- c(1, "x", 2, "y") 
m2 <- c(3, "u", 4, "v") 
dta <- data.frame(m1, m2)

div <- function(x, y) {
  x <- type.convert(x)
  y <- type.convert(y)
  if (is.numeric(x) && is.numeric(y)) x/y else NA
}
transform(dta, ratio = mapply(div, m1, m2))     
##   m1 m2     ratio
## 1  1  3 0.3333333
## x  x  u        NA
## 2  2  4 0.5000000
## y  y  v        NA
```